# Difference between Algumas and Umas in relation to numbers and "tempos"

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu

I understand that Umas is the most common when referring to numbers and tempos, but there seem to be examples where algumas works too, and I have no idea why. I got this from an academic essay so I guess its realiable but not 100% sure.

"Há uns tempos, César parara num «auto-stop» e não levava o cinto de segurança." is apparently right.

"Há alguns tempos, César parara num «auto-stop» e não levava o cinto de segurança. " is wrong

but then "Mas, de alguns tempos para cá, tenho descoberto alguns pontos em que, quase por milagre, ela sobreviveu. " is right?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7ZYV.jpg No idea why..

And the same issue for numbers "Inez Teixeira é uma jovem pintora que tem exposto regularmente desde há uns dois anos" is right

"Inez Teixeira é uma jovem pintora que tem exposto regularmente desde há alguns dois anos. " is wrong

but then "O Massimo esteve dentro do hotel alguns três minutos." and "Agora, só numa semana são alguns quatro ou cinco. " are supposedly both grammatically correct again.

https://imgur.com/a/X8jxoBo No clue why.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: No, umas and algumas cannot be used with numéros and tempos. It has to be uns  and alguns. Those words are masculine, not feminine. It's hard to understand how you might have made those mistakes in asking this question. Há alguns anos **means** a few years ago. You cannot put a number in there. Just like in English: A few two years ago. Right?

Comment: Welcome to Portuguese SE. You might want to include in your question a link to your source: https://ojs.letras.up.pt/index.php/elingUP/article/view/2540

Comment: @Lambie "It's hard to understand how you might have made those mistakes in asking this question" - mental how a non native speaker might be open to the idea that there may be sentences like " Estou aqui umas cinco vezes por dia" where uns does become feminine. That being said, thank you, it makes much more sense thinking of "alguns" as a few rather than some

Comment: vez is feminine. But the feminine does not appear in any of  your examples. Anyway, I can't read the whole article without downloading which I am not prepared to do. Sorry.

Comment: @Lambie Its fine, the question was about the principle of umas/uns in  relation to numbers not confined to examples but thanks anyway

Comment: @Lambie Reading  comprehension is hard but this was never about  "the word number" but actual numbers and when the noun the number is pertaining to is feminine the article also becomes feminine, such as in the example above.

Comment: @Lambie If a word is without quotation marks, it would be safe to assume the person is referencing the object the word is describing and not the word itself. Hence, when people say numbers they usually mean numbers and not the word itself. But glad it is now clear

Answer (score 1):

Restricting myself to pt-BR, the OP examples with "alguns/algumas" all sound quite strange.

And the construction "desde há (uns dois anos)" seems simply wrong, like "since for (some two years)".

Comment: Thank you! It was some essay I found from the University of Porto and they had "O Massimo esteve dentro do hotel alguns três minutos." as correct and it just didnt make sense to me why it would be. But Im trying to learn pt-BR anyway, so if its definitely wrong in Brazil then thats good for me

Comment: Jim, please try and spell correctly. We do still use apostrophes in English. There is nothing worse on a language site to use sloppy spelling. It makes for a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

As Stafusa, I am from Brazil. Even though it would be interesting to see someone from Portugal.

For me, only the two last examples sound wrong, “O Massimo [...]” and “Agora, só [...]”. The example “há alguns dois anos” does sound weirder, but certainly not wrong; if it were “há alguns anos” or “há uns dois anos”, then it would sound totally natural.